# Find child of a sibling - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="clickMe" data-videourl="http://yt.com/123/">click</div>
<div class="somethingElse">blah</div>
<div class="showVideo">
  <iframe class="ytVideo" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

What I need to do is take the `data-videourl` value from `.clickMe` and add it it `.ytVideo`

This is what I'm trying but the `src` is not being set:

```
$('.clickMe').on("click", function() {
  var videoURL = $(this).data('videourl');
  alert(videoURL); <-- a test, this works fine, the data is there
  $(this).next('.showVideo').find('.ytVideo').attr('src',videoURL);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.next()` often trips people up.  It does not find the next sibling of all the siblings that matches the selector you give it.  Instead, it looks ONLY at the next sibling to see if it matches that selector.  That, obviously won't do what you need.

A common design pattern for this type of problem is to use `.closest()` to get a common parent and then use `.find()` to find the desired child.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="clickMe" data-videourl="http://yt.com/123/">click</div>
    <div class="somethingElse">blah</div>
    <div class="showVideo">
       <iframe class="ytVideo" src=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

$('.clickMe').on("click", function() {
  var videoURL = $(this).data('videourl');
  $(this).closest(".container").find('.ytVideo').attr('src',videoURL);
});
```

---

You can also use `.nextAll()` to collect all the siblings that follow your element that match a given selector.

```
$('.clickMe').on("click", function() {
  var videoURL = $(this).data('videourl');
  $(this).nextAll(".showVideo").find('.ytVideo').attr('src',videoURL);
});
```

---

The advantage of using a common parent and `.closest()` is that it is less dependent upon the exact structure of your HTML (and therefore less brittle to change in the HTML).  All it requires is that the target object is somewhere within a common parent.  That's why the use of `.closest()` and then `.find()` on that common parent is such a common design pattern for this type of problem.   Intervening divs could be added to faciliate presentation changes and the code would continue to work.  That is not necessarily true with `.nextAll()` as the target div has to stay at exactly the right level, not just in a common branch.

The performance difference between `.find()` in a branch and `.nextAll()` at a sibling level is rarely significant for any operation triggered by a user's click so it makes sense to code for robustness.

Comment: Thanks for this, would you say `closest()` is a better option than `nextAll()` as it only looks for one? I would have thought faster and more economical?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - see the last paragraph I added to my answer.

Comment: `closest` looks for ancestors, not siblings. Which means you need to use `find` as well. More to write if nothing else.

Comment: @Krycke - it's not any more code that what you suggested since you're using `.nextAll(...).find(...)` which is the same amount of code to write as `.closest(...).find(...)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, yes it is true if you need to find a child in the sibling, but to just find the sibling it's more code.

Answer (score 1):

Next only return the immidiate sibling (`.somethingElse`) and that doesn't match the selector.

Change it to `nextAll()` to select all of them, and then grab the one you want with the selector.

```
$('.clickMe').on("click", function() {
  var videoURL = $(this).data('videourl');
  alert(videoURL); <-- a test, this works fine, the data is there
  $(this).nextAll('.showVideo').find('.ytVideo').attr('src',videoURL);
});
```

Here is the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/nextAll